# Combine elements within a group and get number of occurences across groups using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

The data I'm analyzing has a structure similar to this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group4", "group4", "group4", "group4", "group5", "group5"],
        "letter": ["B1", "B2", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B1", "B2", "B4", "B2", "B1", "B3", "B4", "B3", "B4"]
    })
```

I want to get the possible combination of elements within each group, where the order is not important. For example, for group2 I would like to obtain something like this:

```
group   letter_x  letter_y
group2     B1       B2
group2     B1       B3
group2     B2       B3
```

I've merged the df with itself to obtain the combinations and then got rid of the equal values (e.g. B1B1) this way:

```
df_merge = df.merge(df, left_on='group', right_on='group', how="outer")
df_merge = df_merge[df_merge['letter_x'] != df_merge['letter_y']]
```

But I haven't been able to get rid of the symmetric pairs, meaning that, for example, for group2 I obtain:

```
group   letter_x  letter_y
group2     B1       B2
group2     B1       B3
group2     B2       B1
group2     B2       B3
group2     B3       B1
group2     B3       B2
```

Any ideas?

On the other hand, I want to get the occurrences of each pair across groups in a different dataframe. For instance:

```
letter_x  letter_y  count  groups
  B1        B2        4    (group1,group2,group3,group4)
  B1        B3        2    (group2,group4)
  B1        B4        2    (group3,group4)
  ...
```

My intention was to apply something like this:

```
df_overlap = df_merge.groupby(['letter_x', 'letter_y']).agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).reset_index()
```

And then obtain the counts with the length of the "groups" list in an old-fashioned way using a "for".

For this part, I worry that some elements in the "letter" column will have the mirror pair (as B2B1 in group4) and thus they will have two different counts, whilst I need them to be accounted for as the same.

Any solution for that?
I am open to more efficient ways to do this as well. Thanks!

Comment: You can get the first part with groupby and python's itertools.combinations. For the second part you could use a df like letter, set(groups containing that letter), get the combinations as before and intersect the sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you are looking for `combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

out = (df.sort_values(["group", "letter"])
         .groupby("group")["letter"]
         .apply(lambda d: pd.DataFrame(combinations(d, 2),  columns=["letter_x", "letter_y"]))
         .droplevel(1).reset_index())

print (out.groupby(["letter_x","letter_y"])["group"].agg(["count", tuple]).reset_index())

  letter_x letter_y  count                             tuple
0       B1       B2      4  (group1, group2, group3, group4)
1       B1       B3      2                  (group2, group4)
2       B1       B4      2                  (group3, group4)
3       B2       B3      2                  (group2, group4)
4       B2       B4      2                  (group3, group4)
5       B3       B4      2                  (group4, group5)
```

Comment: I think that's indeed what I was looking for! Thank you very much!